# QByteArray member not found

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application that was written on an Ubuntu desktop system in Qt Creator and I want to compile it on another system (Ubuntu server). This server has no GUI so compilation has to be done through CLI. Upon issuing the make command it begins compiling but throws a compiler error saying:

> error: ‘fromStdString’ is not a member of ‘QByteArray’
>        QByteArray myData = QByteArray::fromStdString(data);

The exact same code works just find on another system and compiles fine. What should I do to fix this problem? Is it an issue with installed libraries on the system or something else?

Comment: I failed to find `QByteArray::fromStdString()` function. Please point Qt documentation where it is defined.

Comment: The question title asks for a QString member, but your code is using a QByteArray. Which one do you really need? Also, tell us which Qt version you use in both systems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is this one, to quote http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromStdString:

> This function was introduced in Qt 5.4.

That is, if you're using Qt5, in Qt4 there is no such member function indeed.

Answer (score 1):

In Qt4, QString::fromStdString() requires Qt to be compiled with STL support, so this may be your problem.

From [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromStdString):

> This constructor is only available if Qt is configured with STL
>   compatibility enabled.

However, if you're using QByteArray, refer to @iksemyonov's answer

Comment: Your link leads to the documentation for the `QString` class, whereas the question is about the `QByteArray` class.

Comment: You're right, I got confused by the title from OP, which states it's a QString member. I'll ask for a clarification

Comment: Looking at the internal implementation of QByteArray and QString, it looks like both your and iksemyonov's answer are related. The `QByteArray::fromStdString` looks like it will only work if STL compatibility is enabled for Qt.